# PHP command line script with no output

Tags: php, command-line

I am working on a hackerrank script and it works for small inputs but with larger inputs for arrays it stops having any output, the echo stops working. No errors, just nothing.

```
$_fp = STDIN;
fscanf($_fp,"%d",$n);

$max = 0.0;
$max_cnt = 0.0;

$board = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

    $points = explode(' ', fgets($_fp));

    $a = intval($points[0]);
    $b = intval($points[1]);

    runBoard2($a, $b);

}


function runBoard2 ($a, $b) {
    global $board, $max, $max_cnt;

    for($r = 0; $r < $a; $r++) {

        for($c = 0; $c < $b; $c++) {
            @$board[$r][$c]  += 1;
            $cellVal = $board[$r][$c];

            if ($cellVal > $max) {
                $max = $cellVal;
                $max_cnt = 1;
            } elseif ($cellVal === $max) {
                $max_cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $max_cnt;
```

stdin.php:

```
2
1000000 1000000
1000000 1000000
```

Commandline call:

```
cat stdin.php | php rectangulargame.php
```

Works with stdin.php:

```
3
2 3
3 7
4 1
```

Thinking it has something to do with this line `@$board[$r][$c]  += 1;` as if I take off the @ suppression to hide notices about undefined offset it shows those messages until it hits an out of memory error. So, any have a suggestion on how I should refactor to avoid this?

Did some more digging and found hints to calculate using mins of rows and cols without building matrices, which after wrapping my head around that in PHP it worked like charm and fast too.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to review and especially for the comments.

Anyone have idea how I can edit this to get the -1 vote to improve?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks, same, processes for couple of seconds then just gives me a new line with a ready prompter.

Comment: You are generating a 1,000,000 x 1,000,000 grid. That's 1,000,000,000,000 entries in your array, and you wonder why you might be out of memory?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to refactor to calculate using just the row and col mins and multiple for final answer.